# How to resolve an Android listview that is not working properly

Tags: android, xml, listview, sax

I am trying to read an XML from the web and display them in a Listview. In the XML I have 3 records and my Listview only showing the last record. Would be great if anyone can help me identifying the mistakes!!
I am using SAX to read from the web.

Handler:

```
public class SearchItemHandler extends DefaultHandler{
private boolean in_itemName=false;
private boolean in_itemAddress=false;
private boolean in_itemLatitude=false;
private boolean in_itemLongitude=false;
private boolean in_business=false;
private boolean in_local=false;

private SearchItem sItem=new SearchItem();
public SearchItem getParsedData(){
    return this.sItem;
}
    public static List<SearchItem> list=new ArrayList<SearchItem>();

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        this.sItem = new SearchItem();
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        // Nothing to do
}
@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI,String localname,String qName,Attributes atts)throws SAXException{
    if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Business")){
        this.in_business=true;
    }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("local")){
        this.in_local=true;
    }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemName")){
        String itemname=atts.getValue("name");
        sItem.setItemName(itemname);
        this.in_itemName=true;
    }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemAddress")){
        String itemaddress=atts.getValue("address");
        sItem.setItemAddress(itemaddress);
        this.in_itemAddress=true;
    }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Latitude")){
        double lat=Double.parseDouble(atts.getValue("lat"));
        sItem.setLatitude(lat);
        this.in_itemLatitude=true;
    }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Longitude")){
        double lon=Double.parseDouble(atts.getValue("lon"));
        sItem.setLatitude(lon);
        this.in_itemLongitude=true;
}
 list.add(sItem);
```

}

> endElement method:

```
    @Override

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localname, String qName)throws SAXException {
        if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Business")){
            this.in_business=false;
        }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("local")){
            this.in_local=false;
        }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemName")){
            this.in_itemName=false;
        }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("ItemAddress")){
            this.in_itemAddress=false;
        }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Latitude")){
            this.in_itemLatitude=false;
        }else if(localname.equalsIgnoreCase("Longitude")){
            this.in_itemLongitude=false;
        }   
}
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
                if(this.in_local){
                //currentCondition.(new String(ch, start, length));
               // sItem.equals(new String(ch,start,length));
        }
    }
```

The Activity:

```
    public class SearchItemListActivity extends ListActivity{
    String param="Bar";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list);

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.webitour.dk/service/localbusiness.aspx?cat="+param);
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/
        SearchItemHandler searchHandler=new SearchItemHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(searchHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        SearchItem sItem=searchHandler.getParsedData();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
        HashMap<String,String> item = new HashMap<String,String>();
        item.put("Name",sItem.getItemName());
        item.put("Address", sItem.getItemAddress());
        list.add(item);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                list,
                R.layout.custom_text_view,
                new String[] {"Name","Address"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
                );

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}

}
```

SearchItem class:

```
    public class SearchItem {
    private String itemName;
    private String itemAddress;

    public SearchItem(){}

    public String getItemName(){
        return this.itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName){
        this.itemName=itemName;
    }
    public String getItemAddress(){
        return this.itemAddress;
    }
    public void setItemAddress(String itemAddress){
        this.itemAddress=itemAddress;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your code carefully then i have found you have done very serious mistake.

By this code you have seen only last record in the list.

Do this this i mention blow.

1-:Create a class with  variable 
  public String Name,Address....

2-:Create a list in SearchItemHandler Class.
  public static List=new List();
  then 
  In the parsing of xml Your should create a Object of your ClassName(Create Above)
  and set the value of each data member of class by xml getValue
  then put this object in list.
  at the end of parsing you find three object in list .

3-: Access this list in SearchItemListActivity class 
    and fatch the value of each object and make a array adapter.

4-:Put this adapter in list then you find three item in list.

I hope this is help if you find any problem please right comment.

Comment: Hi RaviShankar. Thank you for writing. I am trying to follow your suggestion. I have edited my question and put some extra code. I really do not understand how to do point 3 and 4 of your suggestion. so can you please go through my code again and help me a little bit more? Thanks in advance. :)